# Slow request processing in rails, 'waiting for server' message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, response, dispatcher

I have a quite big application, running from inside spree extension. Now the issue is, all requests are very slow even locally. I am getting messages like 'Waiting for localhost" or "waiting for server" in my browser status bar for 3 - 4 seconds for each request issued, before it starts execution. I can see execution time logged in log file is quite good. But overall response time is poor because of initial delay. So please suggest me, where can I start looking into improving this situation?

Comment: Hi, I see this happened long time ago, but did you fix this problem? And if so, do you remember how? I´m facing same problem, I think, and I´m getting completely crazy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26894622/big-delay-while-processing-http-request-from-nginx-to-unicorn-angularjs-to-rail

Comment: Sorry Rober. I don't remember it.

Answer (score 0):

One possible root cause for this kind of problem is that initial DNS name resolution is failing before eventually resolving. You can check if this is the case using `tcpdump` (if that's available for your platform) or [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). Look for taffic to and from your client host on port 53 and see if the name responses are happening in a timely fashion.

If it turns out that this is the problem then you need to make sure that the client is configured such that the first resolver it trys knows about your server addresses (I'm guessing these are local LAN addresses that are failing). Different platforms have different ways of configuring this. A quick hack would be to put the address of your server in the client's hosts file to see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. But I am facing the issue in local host also.

Answer (score -1):

Once you send in your request, you will see 'waiting for host' right up until the Ruby work is done, and it starts sending a response. So, if there is pretty much any processing work that is slowing you down, you'd see this error. What you'd want to do is start looking at the functions that youre seeing the behaviour on, and breaking them down into pieces to see which peices are slow. If EVERYTHING is slow, than you need to look at the things that are common to every function - before functions, or Application Controller code, or something similar. What I do, when I'm just playing around to see what I need to fix is just put 'puts' statements in my code at different stages, to print the current time, then I can see which stage is taking a long time, you know?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I will check all of my before filters.